# What's wrong with this Angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('events.services', [])
    .factory('EventService', function($http, $cordovaSQLite) {
        return {
            test: function() {
                return 'It Works!';
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('NearCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cordovaSQLite, EventService) {
    var test = EventService.test;
    console.log(test); // I expect 'It works' to be here, but returns 'function test();'
})
```

Why doesn't this return 'It Works!' ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you didn't call the function, you instead just referenced it.. `var a = 1; console.log(a); //1`

Comment: Update to `console.log(test());`

Comment: EventsService.test is a function, not a string.

Comment: Why is this a down vote for Seva? Code was provided, and a general question was asked.

Comment: I personally upvoted it since the question was asked in a good format and code was provided, people are downvoting because they forget they were once beginners too.

Comment: @SoEzPz there's a difference in asking a question properly and the long term value of that question....for future readers.  A typo of not invoking a function by leaving out `()` is a very local situation that long term isn't likely to be of great benefit to others. Hover over downvote button will see `not useful` as a downvote reason

Comment: @charletfl thank you for that insightful explanation. That does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, and as per the JS language

In the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

> Calling functions
>   Defining a function does not execute it. Defining the function simply names the function and specifies what to do when the function is called. Calling the function actually performs the specified actions with the indicated parameters. For example, if you define the function square, you could call it as follows:

```
square(5);
```

As you can see, the function requires **()** to be executed.

```
function square(num){
  return num
}

console.log(square);
=> function square(num)

console.log(square( 5 ));
=> 5
```

As you are using your factory,

```
console.log(EventService);
=> { test: function() { return 'It Works!'; }
```

In your scenario, your factory has returned an object with a property **test** that points to an anonymous function.

Simply calling **EventService.test** returns the anonymous function just as it did when we called **console.log(square);**. To utilize the returned function value you must also call it like so

```
EventService.test();
```

Continue to post questions as you see fit, but also remember to troubleshoot your code first, and if you still need to ask a question include all the steps you took to troubleshoot your problem :)